# Cannot start ApacheDS (fresh install)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-ds

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 12, Apache, MySQL, PHP. I am trying to setup ApacheDS on the same machine. So, i install xubuntu, java and apacheds (using the deb package) without a problem. Then, when i try to start ApacheDS by using:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apacheds-2.0.0-M15-default start
```

i get :

```
Starting ApacheDS - default...
$
```

and then if i execute:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apacheds-2.0.0-M15-default status
```

i get:

```
Starting ApacheDS - default is not running
```

I checked /var/log/syslog and there is nothing there!
What is going wrong? Any idea?

Comment: What does your apache (error) log say?

Comment: Nothing! There is nothing logged in the syslog. (Sorry for the delayed answer. Something happened and i was without internet for a few days)

Comment: As mentioned above have a look at your apache error log (ex. /var/log/httpd/error.log) not syslog.

Comment: The OP is running ApacheDS (an LDAP server), which is entirely separate from Apache httpd, the webserver. `/var/log/httpd/error.log` isn't the right log file. (And doesn't exist, in my case, and I have the OP's problem!)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You can see start-up problems in the "console" mode. Just execute:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apacheds-2.0.0-M15-default console
```

In my case I got the following error message, which originated from the "java" command:

```
Running ApacheDS - default...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 1    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
wrapper  | There were 1 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

It was the java options that needed to be fixed. In my case I had to reduce initial heap size:

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx64m  ...
```